# github: how do I delete an attachment in github issues?

Tags: git, github

I am in need to remove an attachment in github issues. How do I do this. When you remove the issue comment, the attachment is still in github. How can I explicitly target to remove an attachment?

The format of such attachments is

https://github.com/<projectname>/<repo>/files/<somenumber>/<filename>.txt

Simple git rm does not work.

Answer (score 26):

It's not possible currently. GitHub allows you, to attach files (`pdf`, `docx` etc.) in comments, but there is no way to delete them.

The behavior is similar to images: you can upload it, but you can't delete it from their cloud.

---

Just in case you uploaded a file that **really** needs to be deleted, there is always a [GitHub Support](https://github.com/c).

Comment: if you're the author if the issue / comment, you can still come and edit your post, thus you should be able to remove the file - but no one else can do this.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri But you can't delete images. Well, you can delete them from the post, but not from their cloud. Like I mentioned, there are needed Suportocat powers to do that.

Comment: I don't think this is limited to owners/collaborators: https://help.github.com/articles/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests/ . In our repository someone used this to host unrelated (potentially harmful) files and we had to ask github support to delete them.

Comment: @wump That's a good point! Seems that was changed. I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm wondering how both GitHub and GitLab are getting away with this in 2019, since GDPR is a thing... https://eugdpr.org/

Comment: You also cannot edit the answer out - the edit history is available forever.

Comment: This is the greatest free image hosting service I've seen. Unlimited quota for everything you need!

Comment: Changing your repository status from private to public or vice versa will delete all previously uploaded files

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can try this link:
https://support.github.com/request?q=delete+issue+attachment
It opens a chatbot, you paste the url of the file and it should do it for you!

Comment: No longer working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [this URL](https://support.github.com/contact?flow=asset_removal&subject=Remove%20image&tags=rr-remove-data) and try the Virtual Agent (it didn't work for me, replying "I don't understand that input" to the image URLs I send it.) or just file a support ticket like this using the account you uploaded the image with.

> I accidentally uploaded an image that contains personal information
> that I don't want to share publicly while submitting an issue. Please
> delete it for me, thanks.
>
> The image URL is:
>
> https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/75155322/265274495-2211b2a5-c757-4f42-9ed0-864a7809ad9e.png

Be aware that there are two URLs for an image you uploaded to a issue or comment, before redirect it starts with https://github.com/User/Repository/assets/, after redirect it starts with something like
https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/, I'm not sure which one is needed to delete an image or both is OK, I'll update this answer (hopefully) after they replied my ticket.

Update: According to GitHub Support, Just providing one of the two URLs is OK, but the Virtual Assistant isn't working now.