# I'm having issues deleting image files on my github repository

Tags: github

is there any suggestions on what to do?, I'm currently having issues with deleting image files from github repository. Here is the message i got "We’ve detected the file has mixed line endings. When you commit changes we will normalize them to Windows-style (CRLF)".

What i mean is that, after deleting, changes cant be committed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github: how do I delete an attachment in github issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215211/github-how-do-i-delete-an-attachment-in-github-issues)

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215211/github-how-do-i-delete-an-attachment-in-github-issues) says that you can't delete an image from GitHub.

However, as a work around, you can follow below steps:

1. You can clone the repository to your computer or do a pull in the project folder.
2. Delete the image files you intend to delete.
3. Commit and Push the changes to remote Repository.