# When do files uploaded in Github issues get deleted?

Tags: github

If you upload a file to an issue and then remove the issue comment the attachment is still in github.
The format of such attachments is

https://github.com///files//.txt

Any ideea if it gets deleted when no longer linked and if yes after how much time?

Comment: GitHub makes no guarantees about whether it's preserved or not and if so, for how long.  If you need a more definitive answer, you'll need to ask GitHub Support.

Answer (score 0):

The "[File attachments on issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-your-work-on-github/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests)" current (Oct. 2020) official documentation does not mention anything about deletion.

And the question "[How do I delete an attachment in github issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33215776/6309)" confirmed it is not possible for now to delete said attachment, not without contacting [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/).